# Adding a drawable resource

Tags: android

:)
I have my "drawable" folder inside "res" but when I try to add a new resource to it (rightClick -> new -> file -> browse for a jpg and png file) the autogenerated R doesn't see it (in Package Explorer R.java-> R -> drawable ->  sees only the "icon"). I tried with Project -> Clean and with an xml bitmap declaration inside the drawable. What could it be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This happened to me a few times as well.

Try choosing Project -> Clean from menu and wait a while.

If this doesn't help, clean and eclipse restart might help.

Comment: With drag'n'drop on the drawable resource the problem seems to be solved. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2):

If you have space in name of your application than sometimes resources are not visible. Try to remove space. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Are there perhaps errors in any other file in the resource folder? This could prevent R from being generated thus not showing your new drawables. (If there is an error, this will also show up in your console.)

Answer (score 0):

Try restarting Eclipse, and refresh your current project.

Answer (score 0):

what kind of error do you get ? cannot be resolved or is not a field ?
this is kind of rude but I often delete the entire "gen" folder of my projects, to force regenerating the R.java

Answer (score 0):

after you add a file .. You should recompile your Project to see your New Resource !

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you are importing the R class.

```
import com.example.prettyprojectname.R;
```